# How do you prevent yourself from changing the system date and time in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

How do you prevent yourself from changing the system date and time in Windows 8?

Comment: Use a group policy and disable your ability to do it

Comment: How do you change it accidentally?

Comment: Can you clarify the nature of the problem?  How does it currently get changed?  As the question is written, one solution could be, "get counselling"

Comment: I would suspect he is testing preventing *others* from changing the date.  SadBunny's solution is what I used to prevent contractors from lying about a job.  We discovered they could lie to the remote system by changing the time on their local computers, due to poorly written 3rd party software.  However, they needed Admin access to their computers.  So we removed that ability.  Yes, as admins, they could change the policy, but that was beyond their knowledge and they knew we were looking now.

Comment: OR... He is the kind of person who checks three times a day on what day Christmas will fall this year to see if it will pay off to ask for leave time to connect it to the weekend, and then accidentally clicks that actual date. (Which is why I had to look this same information up last year, lol)

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by changing your local policy settings.

1. Enter the Local Security Policy editor. (Windows key + R, opens Run window, type **secpol.msc**, then run that command.)
2. In the left pane of the now opened Local Security Policy window, open the **Local Policies** folder, then click **User Rights Assignment**.
3. In the right pane, look for, then double click on **Change the time zone**
4. A window opens with the settings for users/groups having access to changing the system clock. Normally (i.e. by default), this should show:

   - Administrators
   - LOCAL SERVICE
   - Users
5. If you are using an account with administrative rights, remove **Administrators** and **Users**.
   **NOTE:** If you use a limited account (or just want to block limited accounts), just remove **Users**.
   **NOTE:** Do not remove "LOCAL SERVICE".
   **NOTE:** If you want, you can of course also allow specific users/groups to still access this setting.)
6. Finalize by clicking OK, and yes I'm sure, etc. until done.

Good luck!